# Clarification on throw expressions

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.0

I'm reading the section on "Throw Expressions" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#throw-expressions).

It mentions you can use them now on "...conditional expressions, null coalescing expressions, and some lambda expressions."

But they didn't provide clear examples for each except for one they referred to as conditional but I thinks it's null coalescing. Anyway, I want to provide an example for each three.

Are these (in my comments) correctly named throw expression examples for conditional expressions, null coalescing expressions, and a lambda expressions? Or did I mislabel/mix up any?

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; }

        // null coalescing expression.
        public Person(string name) => Name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(name);

        // conditional expressions
        public string GetFirstName()
        {
            var parts = Name.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            return (parts.Length > 0) ? parts[0] : throw new InvalidOperationException("No name!");
        }
        // Lambda
        public string GetLastName() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: You are correct. You can also refer to [SO documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/1936/c-sharp-7-0-features/20215/throw-expressions#t=201702020703012064675) Or the latest -afaik- [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#throw-expressions) related with C# 7.0 release

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your understanding is correct. In C# 7 you can use `throw` in these places you couldn't before:

- Conditional expressions (the ternary or `?:` operator)
- Null coalescing expressions (the `??` operator)
- Lambda expressions such as expression-bodied members

As described in the article you linked to, `throw` has always been a statement in C# (not an expression), which meant you couldn't use it like:

```
var theValue = myNullable.HasValue
    ? myNullable.Value
    : throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

Instead, you'd need to split up the assignment statement:

```
var theValue = myNullable.HasValue ? myNullable.Value : null;
if (theValue == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

This is a silly example, of course, but it demonstrates how it's sometimes useful to be able to throw inside structures like the conditional operator.

A great example that wraps up two of the new uses for the `throw` expression is an expression-bodied `set` accessor:

```
public string Name
{
    get => name;
    set => name = value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
```